# AngularJS support multiple environments

Tags: angularjs, configuration, provisioning

What is the conventional way to support multiple environments(develop, staging, production, ci) in an AngularJS application?

For a more concrete example, how would one go about provisioning(probably requires an additional tool) a server endpoint in a config somewhere and then read that server endpoint in for use elsewhere, such as calls like `$http.get(server_endpoint+'/rest/api/route'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an Angular constant, inject it into the required service/controller and refer to environment-specific values

```
angular.module('YourApp')
.constant('AppConstants', {
   'SERVER_ENDPOINT': 'http://api.example.com',
   'SHOW_DEBUG': true
});
```

You would use that like

```
$http.get(AppConstants.SERVER_ENDPOINT + '/rest/api/route')
```

If you use Grunt or Gulp, there's a nice task that allows you to create an Angular constant file based on the environment.

[grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant)

[gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant)

Grunt example:

```
ngconstant: {
            options: {
                name: 'config',
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/config.js'
                },
                constants: {
                    ENV: {
                        FB_APP_ID: '123456'
                    }
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/config.js'
                },
                constants: {
                    ENV: {
                        FB_APP_ID: '98765'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The tasks that create the production and development version of the app call `ngconstant:prod` and `ngconstant:dev` respectively

Comment: is there any particular file where the  `angular.module('YourApp')...` block should be located?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you define the constant, but it is standard practice to  put it in its own file, say appconstants.js, similar to putting each controller/service/filter/directive in a separate file.